# When does a reference need to be atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading

What does it mean for a reference to be assigned atomically in Java?

- I do understand what it means for a long and double, that is: a thread can see partially constructed number,
- but for an object I don't understand since assignment does not mean copy just pointing to an address in memory

So what could have been wrong if reference assignment was not atomic in Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This means that you will not get the corrupted reference ever. Suppose that you have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    Object obj = null;
}
```

In memory `obj` is a null pointer, usually it's an integer number like `0x00000000`. Then suppose that in one thread you have an assignment:

```
this.obj = new Object();
```

Suppose that `new Object()` is allocated in the memory and has the pointer like `0x12345678`. The reference atomicity ensures that when you check the `obj` from another thread you will either have a null pointer (`0x00000000`) or pointer to the new object (`0x12345678`). But under no circumstances you can get the partially assigned reference (like `0x12340000`) which points to nowhere.

This might look obvious, but such problem may appear in low-level languages like `C` depending on the CPU architecture and memory alignment. For example if your pointer is misaligned and crosses the cache line, it's possible that it will not be synchronously updated. In order to avoid such situation Java virtual machine always aligns pointers, so they never cross the cache line.

So were the Java references non-atomic, there would be a chance when dereferencing the reference written from another thread that you get not the object which was referenced before or after the assignment, but random memory location (which may lead to segmentation fault, corrupted heap or any other disaster).

Comment: *partially constructed reference*. I find this line to be a bit incorrect.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: is it better now?

Comment: What I was trying to point is that the reason why we need an atomic reference is to avoid threads from using a reference to a partially constructed object. Instead of *partially constructed reference*, your answer should read *reference to a partially constructed object*. (In my opinion)

Comment: @ChetanKinger, OPs question is not about `AtomicReference` class, it's about Java Memory Model. It's not about the partially constructed objects, it's about references themselves which can be stored non-atomically.

Comment: From what I understand, a pointer on 64bit systems is usually a long (8 bytes) and not an integer. Anyway, +1 for a clear explanation and for context I found the following answers helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11964034/3080094 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/15201349/3080094

Comment: @vanOekel, I used 32 bits just as illustration. Actually Hotspot JVM often uses 32bit references even on 64bit systems: if you set -Xmx lower than 4Gb, then all references will fit the 32bits and if you set -Xmx lower than 32Gb, there's a "compressed oops" feature which also allows you to fit the pointers in 32bits. Exact pointer length is not specified by JVM specification and is up to implementation (I wonder if it's useful to have 48bit pointers?..)

Comment: If you could get a corrupted reference, that would be a gaping security hole.

Answer (score 10):

Let's consider the classic double checked locking example to understand why a reference needs to be atomic :

```
class Foo {
    private Helper result;
    public static Helper getHelper() {
        if (result == null) {//1
            synchronized(Foo.class) {//2
               if (result == null) {//3
                    result = new Helper();//4
                }
            }
        }
        return result//5;
    }

    // other functions and members...
}
```

Let's consider 2 threads that are going to call the `getHelper` method :

1. Thread-1 executes line number 1 and finds `result` to be `null`.
2. Thread-1 acquires a class level lock on line number 2
3. Thread-1 finds `result` to be `null` on line number 3
4. Thread-1 starts instantiating a new `Helper`
5. While Thread-1 is still instantiating a new `Helper` on line number 4, Thread-2 executes line number 1.

Steps 4 and 5 is where an inconsistency can arise. There is a possibility that at Step 4, the object is not completely instantiated but the `result` variable already has the address of the partially created `Helper` object stamped into it. If Step-5 executes even a nanosecond before the `Helper` object is fully initialized,Thread-2 will see that `result` reference is not `null` and may return a reference to a partially created object.

A way to fix the issue is to mark `result` as `volatile` or use a `AtomicReference`. That being said, the above scenario  is highly unlikely to occur in the real world and there are better ways to implement a `Singleton` than using double-checked locking.

[Here's](https://blogs.oracle.com/cwebster/entry/double_check_locking_part_2) an example of implementing double-checked locking using `AtomicReference` :

```
private static AtomicReference instance = new AtomicReference();

public static AtomicReferenceSingleton getDefault() {
     AtomicReferenceSingleton ars = instance.get();
     if (ars == null) {
         instance.compareAndSet(null,new AtomicReferenceSingleton());
         ars = instance.get();
     }
     return ars;
}
```

If you are interested in knowing why Step 5 can result in memory inconsistencies, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789287/constructors-and-instruction-reordering) answer (as suggested by [pwes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283519/pwes) in the comments)

Comment: @ChetanKinger -  **A way to fix the issue is to mark result as volatile or use a AtomicReference** but volatile only has relevance to modifications of the variable itself, not the object it refers to right?

Comment: @user3320018 AtomicReference's code uses `volatile` internally for the referenced object. It has nothing to do with the object's contents, which must do the same where required, or use proper synchronization

Comment: Ok cool. Another question - so the reference (not concrete object on heap) assignment itself needs two operations, am I right?

Comment: @user3320018 As far as my understanding goes, the creation of a memory location and it's initialization is definitely a multiple step process and that's where the inconsistency can arise.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you are asking about `AtomicReference<V>`.

The idea is that if two or more threads read or update the value of a variable of reference type, you might get unexpected results. For example, suppose each thread checks if some reference type variable is null, and if it's null, creates an instance of that type and updates that reference variable.

This may cause two instances to be created if both threads see that the variable is null at the same time. If your code relies on all threads working with the same instance referred by that variable, you'll get in trouble.

Now, if you use `AtomicReference<V>`, you can solve this problem by using the `compareAndSet(V expect, V update)` method. So a thread will update the variable only if some other thread didn't beat it to it.

For example :

```
static AtomicReference<MyClass> ref = new AtomicReference<> ();

... 
// code of some thread
MyClass obj = ref.get();
if (obj == null) {
    obj = new MyClass();
    if (!ref.compareAndSet (null, obj)) // try to set the atomic reference to a new value
                                        // only if it's still null
        obj = ref.get(); // if some other thread managed to set it before the current thread,
                         // get the instance created by that other thread
}
```

Comment: This is not perfect, as you might create two `MyClass` objects, which may be undesireable. Plain synchronized inside would help.

Comment: Indeed, the classic singleton example is not a good way to show this.

Comment: @pwes Yes, a redundant MyClass instance may be created by this code, but it won't be assigned to the atomic reference, and all threads will use the same instance. I agree it's not a perfect example.